# How to refer sub-figures without using captions

Tags: latex

[Figure explaining  what i want to do exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay9Gw.png)

I am using the following code to add figures in main body of the text. I need to ref figures in main body like Fig 1a, Fig 2a. but i dont want to add caption of figure 1a when adding the figure in latex code.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}  
  \caption{``Conversation Starter'' of March}
  \label{fig:csmarch}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{``Conversation Starter'' of April}
  \label{fig:csapril}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{``Conversation Starter'' of May}
  \label{fig:csmay}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{``Conversation Starter'' of June}
  \label{fig:csjune}
\end{subfigure} 
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{``Conversation Starter'' of July}
  \label{fig:csjuly}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{``Conversation Starter'' of the \#NigeriaDecides}
  \label{fig:csds}
\end{subfigure}
```

Answer (score 10):

The `subcaption` package provides `\phantomsubcaption` for this kind of problem. From the manual:

> If you don’t want to give a sub-figure a caption, because the picture itself already contains the caption, or for some other reason, you can use the command
> `\phantomsubcaption`
> instead of `\subcaption`, or – when inside a `subfigure` or `subtable` environment
> – `\phantomcaption` instead of `\caption`. `\phantomsubcaption` and
> `\phantomcaption` do not have any arguments, and they do not generate any output,
> but give you an anchor for a `\label` command which can be placed afterwards. Furthermore
> it increases the sub-figure resp. sub-table counter.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    
    Hello world! I am referencing to figures \ref{fig:a}, \ref{fig:b}, \ref{fig:c} and \ref{fig:img}.
    
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \phantomsubcaption
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \phantomsubcaption
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
\\
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \phantomsubcaption
        \label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \phantomsubcaption
        \label{fig:img}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[See the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOalg.png)

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved. I have changed the sub figure code with the following.

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\begin{subfigure}{0pt}
\caption{\label{fig:csmarch}}
\end{subfigure}
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep `\subfigure` like this will give output `no caption` and `\subfigure[]` (`[]` empty)will give output like `(a)` `(b)` & `(c)` and if you use any caption like my last 3 `\subfigure` then it will give output like `(d) Caption 4` & `(e) Caption 5` & `(f) Caption 6`.

> Note: `figure*` is for the multicolumn article. You can use `figure` for the single-column article. `[ht!]` google it or [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/%60!h%27_float_specifier_changed_to_%60!ht%27) or [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_of_Figures)

> Use proper packages

```
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    \usepackage{subfloat}
    \usepackage{float}
```

And then use code like this

```
 \begin{figure*}[ht!]
        \centering
            \subfigure[] 
            {
                \label{subfig:lab1}
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{figures/1.pdf} % .png .jpg ... according to supported graphics files
            } 
            %
            \subfigure[] 
            {
                \label{subfig:lab2}
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{figures/2.pdf} % .png .jpg ... according to supported graphics files
            }
            %
            \subfigure[] 
            {
                \label{subfig:lab3}
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{figures/3.pdf} % .png .jpg ... according to supported graphics files
            }\\ % for new row or line of subfigures
            %
            \subfigure[Caption 4] 
            {
                \label{subfig:lab4}
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{figures/4.pdf} % .png .jpg ... according to supported graphics files
            }
            %
            \subfigure[Caption 5] 
            {
                \label{subfig:lab6}
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{figures/5.pdf} % .png .jpg ... according to supported graphics files
            }
            %
            \subfigure[Caption 6] 
            {
                \label{subfig:lab6}
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{figures/6.pdf} % .png .jpg ... according to supported graphics files 
            }
            %
        \caption{Figure Caption}
        \label{fig:Figure ref}
        \end{figure*}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Mixing different subfigure packages is prone to cause problems.  Decide if you want to use `subfigure` or `subcaption`, but not both.